# Double Pointer Question

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, tree

I am trying to make a tree template that can have any number of children on each node. This is my code for an addChild function in the node class -

```
template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::Node::addChild(T& value) {
    Node* temp = new Node(value, this); //second parameter is for parent
    numOfChildren++;
    children*[numOfChildren] = temp;
}
```

Instead of having a pointer for a left and right child, I thought I should make a double pointer (pointer to an array of Node*).

Node** children;

I keep getting an "Expected primary expression before '[' token" error. I'm guess I am accessing the 2D array wrong then? Or maybe I should just go about it a different way? Do you think it would work if I just had children as

Node* children
?

I feel like it might work if I just have a Node* and each element be a different Node.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are creating a *B-Tree*.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree.  You may want to search the web for existing examples.  Also search for "Balanced B-Tree".

Comment: I guess what you WANTED to do is (*children)[numOfChildren] (however, you must not dereference if you want to assing a Note*. Erik's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `children[numOfChildren]`. Or do it the right way with `std::vector<Node *> children;`

Comment: However, when I do the line std::vector<Tree<T>::Node*> children;, I get an error saying error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'

Comment: `std::vector<Node *>` should work fine inside `Tree` or `Node`, no need for `Tree<T>::Node`. Post source if it still fails.

Comment: @Sterling: you are missing a `typename` there. Basically `Tree<T>::Node` is a dependent name, and during the first pass of the template compilation process it is assuming that it is not a type. You have to tell the compiler that it is. Google/SO search for "dependent name" (Actual fix: `std::vector<typename Tree<T>::Node*> children;`) Otherwise, since you are in the context of `Tree<>` you can just use `Node` and the compiler will know (from the context) that it is a type.